# How do I fill my searchable drop down with text after an item is selected?

Tags: react-native

I'm a beginner learning React Native, and I'm working on a first project that requires a drop down search bar. I did some research and [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-searchable-dropdown) is exactly the type of component I'm looking for. I want to be able to type into the search bar, have options appear under, and then when clicked on, the search bar fills up with that option. Ultimately, I'm trying to make something like [this](https://www.terradle.com/). My problem is, I can't seem to find a property that allows me to directly change the text contents of the searchable drop down. After I click the item from the drop down, the drop down disappears and the search bar stays empty (with the placeholder). Although it would still work if I selected my item this way, it would be much preferred to populate the textbox first and then press a button to submit the chosen item. Does anybody know how to go about doing this?

Here is what it looks like right now:

```
const StandSearch = () => {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [selectedStand, setSelectedStand] = useState(null);

  const { stands } = standData;

  const filteredStands = stands.filter((stand) =>
    stand.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase())
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.dropdownContainer}>
      <SearchableDropdown
        onItemSelect={(item) => {
          setSelectedStand(item);
          setSearchQuery(item.name); // Update the text input value
        }}
        onTextChange={(text) => setSearchQuery(text)}
        textInputStyle={styles.dropdownInput}
        itemStyle={styles.dropdownItem}
        itemTextStyle={styles.dropdownItemText}
        items={filteredStands}
        placeholder="Type any stand to begin"
        resetValue={false}
        defaultValue={searchQuery} // Set the initial value
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
const [placeHolder,setPlaceHolder] =useState("")
```

and update `placeHolder` value whenever user selects an item on `onItemSelect` with `setPlaceHolder(item or item.name)` since it doesn't seems like component you have using have value prop this might work

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your suggestion. I tried this method, and some interesting things occur. First of all, I'm testing my application on both my iphone and my web browser. When on my phone, when I click the item it appears in the textbox as a placeholder. However, on PC, after I click on the item, the drop down disappears just like before and nothing appears in the search box.